# Easily switching between feed_dict and queues for input to TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Right now I have a model configured to take its inputs with `feed_dict`. The code looks something like this:

```
# model.py
class MyModel(object):
  def __init__(self, hyperparams):
    self.build_model(hyperparams)

  def build_model(self, hps):
    self.input_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[hps.batch_size, hps.nfeats])
    self.labels = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[hps.batch_size])
    # Define hidden layers, loss, training step, etc.

# train.py
model = MyModel(hps)
for _ in range(100):
  x, y = some_python_function() # Read a batch from disk, preprocess
  sess.run(model.train_step, feed_dict={model.input_data: x, model.labels: y})
```

For performance reasons, I'd like to switch to using queues for training. But I'd like to maintain the ability to use `feed_dict`, e.g. for inference or testing.

Is there an elegant way to do this? What I'd like to do is, when using queues, 'swap out' the placeholder variables for the tensors returned by my queue's dequeue op. I thought that `tf.assign` would be the way to do this, i.e.:

```
single_x, single_y = tf.parse_single_example(...)
x, y = tf.train.batch([single_x, single_y], batch_size)
model = MyModel(hps)
sess.run([tf.assign(model.input_data, x), tf.assign(model.labels, y)])
for _ in range(100):
  sess.run(model.train_step)
```

But this raises `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'`. The API docs for [`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) describe the first argument as: "A mutable `Tensor`. Should be from a `Variable` node. May be uninitialized." Does this mean my placeholders aren't mutable? Can I make them so? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Minimal runnable example [here](https://gist.github.com/colinmorris/8ca883c04831c755ee3bc745cab52761).

Answer (score 3):

You could separate the creation of the `Variables` and the `Operations` by:

- adding a `build_variables` method called at the instantiation of your `Model` class,
- changing the interface of the `build_model` method so it accepts your `x`and `y` tensors as arguments and so it builds the model `operations` based on them.

This way you would reuse the variables and constants of your model. The downside being that the operations will be duplicated for the `placeholder` version and any other version.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

BATCH_SIZE = 2

class Model(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.build_variables()

  def build_variables(self):
    self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))

  def build_model(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.output = tf.matmul(self.x, self.w)
    self.loss = tf.losses.absolute_difference(self.y, self.output)


model = Model()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def placeholder_run():
  x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, 3])
  y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, 1])
  model.build_model(x, y)

  for i in range(3):
    x = np.random.rand(BATCH_SIZE, 3)
    y = x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    loss = sess.run(model.loss, feed_dict={model.x:x, model.y:y})
    print(loss)

def nonph_run():
  x = tf.random_normal([BATCH_SIZE, 3])
  y = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1, keep_dims=True)
  model.build_model(x, y)
  for i in range(3):
    loss = sess.run(model.loss)
    print(loss)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Works
    placeholder_run()
    # Doesn't fail
    nonph_run()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of your graph and know what you want upfront, you could use a switch on your input. For example,

```
x_plh = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, myshape)
x_dsk = my_input_from_disk()
use_dsk = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, ())
x = tf.cond(use_dsk, lambda: x_dsk, lambda: x_plh)
```

If you want a more flexible solution and take the somewhat pioneer route, you could have a go a the [`Dataset`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/datasets.md) API of tensorflow. Take time to go through the doc, it is a nice read. A single `Iterator` can have several initializers using different `Dataset`s, which could fit your case.